# facing problems during parsing HTML to XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using WPF Rich Editor Library open source control. which i got  from
http://wpfricheditorlibrary.codeplex.com/

The XML parser of this control missing `<Table.Columns>` opening and closing attributes, which is very needful to create table in xaml.

The required parsing output should be:

```
 <FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
            <Section FontFamily="tahoma" FontSize="11px"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph>
                <Table>
                    **<Table.Columns>**
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                        **</Table.Columns>**
                    <TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>
                <Paragraph>
                    <LineBreak />
                </Paragraph>
            </Section>
        </FlowDocument>
```

but the xml parser return excluding `<Table.Columns>` tag:

```
  <FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
            <Section FontFamily="tahoma" FontSize="11px"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph>
                <Table>
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableColumn Width="100" />
                    <TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="Black" ColumnSpan="1"><Paragraph><LineBreak /></Paragraph></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>
                <Paragraph>
                    <LineBreak />
                </Paragraph>
            </Section>
        </FlowDocument>
```

Please suggest what should i do?

Comment: You say that the parser is in the control? Did you debug it? It can be a possible bug in the control maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the parser. I filed an issue: https://wpfricheditorlibrary.codeplex.com/workitem/8936